# How can I get this effect in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I would like to have some views and I expect that when I click continue the next view is kind of dragged into the screen with a horizontal animation
I'll leave the link to a video of how it's supposed to work on Figma
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B6sVt2m42JYC17lK7m7qZzcSUJ4fXVhK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieve by using 'SlideTransition'

```
SlideTransition(
  position: Tween<Offset>(
  begin: const Offset(0, 1),
  end: Offset.zero,
).animate(animation),child: child,),
```

For More details read here - [SlideTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html)